# HTML format for resume upload

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

On Stack Overflow we are a bunch of developers. We all for sure like to show off our talent in our resumes. Frontend developers do their resumes in HTML. I did. I had to convert it to PDF and the HTML-to-PDF convertors are poor. How come Stack Overflow jobs does not allow HTML resume uploads?

Comment: `How come stackoverflow jobs does not allow HTML resume uploads?` because there's no guarantee how it will be rendered. There *is* a guarantee with PDFs. Better for everyone involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons why this probably won't work as well as you'd anticipate:

Many employers are still running on old browsers; does your HTML resumé render well in IE8?

We'd have to sanitize all the inbound HTML to eliminate things like script attacks. Sure, we do that for the main site anyway, and we virus scan all uploads but it's a constant battle with new attacks. Sending such things to employers would be bad form.

We also convert pretty much all resumés to PDF for employers so that they don't have to handle a myriad of different resumé types. We still provide a link to the original document but you shouldn't assume that employer is necessarily going to be able to accurately render the HTML document that you send through.

In short, it'd be best to assume that employers will print your resumé, photograph it on a [wooden table](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/Web_0_0x2e_1), then re-email it to themselves...

Comment: I guess there's nothing stopping one from hosting it somewhere (even as a github page etc...) and linking to it if they really wanted to point it out...

Comment: +1 that makes more sense. Consider a link to a portfolio of your work showing a prospective employer what you're capable of.

Comment: +1 but only for your last sentence because it's #truth. Otherwise, sounds like a bunch of **EXCUSES!!!** ;-)